# Following clone of Fedora Core 30 Server to new hardware, one nic is "missing" but is seen by various utilities; how can I set its configuration?

Tags: networking, fedora, network-interface

It was time for new hardware... Never mind the "big picture" but I ended up finding a bug in Fedora Core 31 server that I didn't want to live with, so I loaded on the disk an image snapshot of another system which has FC 30. Both the new hardware and this older image were for systems with two NICs (network interface cards). I think the FC31 saw both NICs without any trouble and so I didn't think much about it before I overlaid the older system onto the disk, but now I'm having trouble getting one of the two NICs functional.

The one that's working is an Intel port and the other, that isn't working, is a Realtek - they're both built into the motherboard. `ifconfig` shows the working one as device `enp3s0`. I would have expected the other one to be something like enp4s0, but no, it's apparently known as "`vibr0`", which I've never heard of before. `ifconfig` said this port has an IP address assigned but where it came from I have no idea since it's an IP address that's not a part of my network - namely, it's 192.168.122.1. Wherever that number came from, if I could only figure out how to set it to what I need, I'd be good to go! But, I'm having trouble figuring out where this one is configured - `grep`ping in /`etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` showed no matches for 122, and of course there's no `ifcfg-vibr0`, either. (I do have a DHCP server in the environment but it provides addresses in a different subnet, and besides, I need to set this to a fixed IP address to talk directly to the outside world.)

So, I was looking for more data. I've had this crazy idea that maybe all I need to do is create the right script in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` and then do an `ifup` command and all would be good. Aside from `ifup` being deprecated, it did try to work and would continually tell me there was a name mismatch but also it kept trying to use `enp3s0`, which is already in use and working fine. (More on this below.)

`lspci` had some interesting data but it was more than needed, so I used `ip link` as well. Interestingly, `ip link` shows there's also a "`vibr0-nic`", and so I installed `lshw` and it shows a lot more data:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.1
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d800(size=256) memory:f760f000-f760ffff memory:f7604000-f7607fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: virbr0
       serial: [redacted]
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.122.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: [redacted]
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

I think the "unclaimed" part is curious, as is the fact that there's ONE port for the Realtek, but somehow it thinks there are two devices? In any event, the port is plugged in to a really slow network router, so it's nice to note that it is correctly recognized as a 10Mbit/s link. It also thinks there's a driver, etc.

I tried adding several new files to `network-scripts` to try and configure this thing, including `ifcfg-enp4s0 ifcfg-vibr0` and `ifcfg-vibr0-nic`, all modeled off of the working `ifcfg-enp3s0`. Notably, I DID get an error from `ifup` about the device name, but it seems wrong, for example, trying `vibr0` yielded:

> Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this
>   connection (device enp3s0 not available because profile is not
>   compatible with device (mismatching interface name)).

Perhaps I can formulate the name more correctly? `lspci` reports, regarding the Realtek device:

```
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 816e (rev 1a)
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 1a)
04:00.2 Serial controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 816a (rev 1a)
04:00.7 IPMI Interface: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 816c (rev 1a)
```

Does that help?

I'd rather get this working than add another NIC to the system - anyone?

**UPDATE**

I logged in to another FC 30 box and found it also has the vibr0 nic entry, and it also gave it this exact same address?! Curious! *This means it cannot have come from some `dhcp` server somewhere on the net.* ...Perhaps it has been there all along and I just never noticed before? I'm not sure but that's hard to imagine.

Comment: Are you, or have you used, KVM/QEMU in the past? These NICs were added to my system after I installed QEMU.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I'm not sure what you're referring to - "KVM" to me is a switch one uses in a server farm to have one Keyboard, Video and Mouse and can select what server they attach to; in this context, IDK what you're asking. ...Note that I'm about to update this question a little!

Comment: KVM = Kernel-based Virtual Machine. For more info on virbr0, check this out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/246343/what-is-the-virbr0-interface-used-for#246346